# A line passes through the points,(−2,−15) and (2,−3). Find the equation of a perpendicular line that passes through the point (6,4)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to answer the following:

> A line passes through the points (−2,−15) and (2,−3). Find the equation of a perpendicular line that passes through the point (6,4).

The solution is provided:
$y = -\frac{1}{3}x+6$.

However, I arrived at $y = \frac{1}{3}x + 2$.

Here is my working. Where did I go wrong?

First find m based on the two points:
$m = \frac{y1-y}{x1-x}$ = $\frac{15-3}{-2-2}$ = $\frac{14}{-4}$ = $-3$.

So, if $m=-3$, then, since it's a question about a perpendicular line, I need to find the negative reciprocal. The reciprocal of $-3$ is $\frac{1}{-3}$; therefore, the negative reciprocal is just $\frac{1}{3}.$

Now I can plug in my parameters. I am to find the perpendicular line that crosses point (6,4).

$y = mx + b$

$4 = \frac{1}{3}(6) + b$

$4 = 2 + b$

$b = 2$

Thus, $y = \frac{1}{3}x + 2$

How can I arrive at $y = -\frac{1}{3}x+6$ ?

Comment: m=$\frac{-15+3}{-2-2}$=3(not -3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the slope of the line passing through $(-2,-15)$ and $(2,-3)$ was mistaken.

That slope should be $\dfrac{-15+3}{-2-2}=3$ or $\dfrac{-3+15}{2+2}=3$, not $-3$.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. An early mistake cascaded all the way down.

Comment: As $x$ increases from $-2$ to $2$, $y$ increases from $-15$ to $-3$, so the slope must be positive